# Cannot load Main program for javafx document

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a document, but when I try to load the main, I get this error:

> Error resolving onAction='#LoadDB', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.

**This is my code:**

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Database Database = new Database();
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("GUI.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

How do I fix the problem?

Comment: According to the error message, your error is fairly clearly in the FXML file and/or controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must implément the method  `LoadDB` that been defined in the FXML file, to fix that, in your controller add this :

```
@FXML
void LoadDB(ActionEvent event) { }.
```

or just remove the action